# Bootstrap Carousel bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

So I have a simple carousel made on bootstrap and what I want is when we enter the carousel the slide to stop.
Everything works but when the mouse enters a problem happens. The div that has to disappear doesn't slide but disappears

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({interval: 1000})
    .on('slid', function (e) { $(this).carousel({interval:false}); });
});
</script>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ferkp/

Comment: By default Bootstrap's carousel stops the timer when you hover it, is that what you want? no need for customization there

Comment: Yes but same screwed effect comes, guess i'll switch to fade effect

Comment: So the issue is that when you hover over the carousel *as it is sliding* the item that is sliding out of view disappears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of research, it seems that this was [a known bug in Bootstrap 2.x](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7005).

By upgrading to Bootstrap 3.0, the appearance of the carousel gets changed, but the bug is fixed. You can grab the CSS and JS from a CDN:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Oh, and you might still want to include the result from the other answer (that's now deleted, it seems) and change `$(this).carousel({ interval: false });` to `$(this).carousel('pause');`, otherwise that piece of code doesn't do anything.

And if upgrading to Bootstrap 3.0 isn't an option for some reason, there's a method provided on the [bug report page](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/7005) to edit the Bootstrap Javascript itself to fix the bug in 2.x.

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ferkp/2/)